# can not post a picture in FB post , This status update appears to be blank. Please write something or attach a link or photo to update your status

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, webbrowser-control

I am Trying to post a picture and text on facebook page using webbrowser control.

I Paste a url in text area, when it gets the thumbnail I send keys (ctrl+A). And then send the text via send `keys.Send(...)`
Everything works fine until click post button 
it gives Error

```
"This status update appears to be blank. Please write something or attach a link or photo to update your status."
```

I have tried to set all attributes of Textarea, like title, inner text, and placeholder, and I am sure Text area is also not null.

```
HtmlElement elementTextArea = null;
HtmlElementCollection elemss = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea");
foreach (HtmlElement elem in elemss)
{
    if (elem.GetAttribute("name") == "xhpc_message")
    {
        elementTextArea = elem;
        break;
    }
}
elementTextArea.Focus();
Print("\nSet Focused\n");

SendText(url);

webBrowser1.Update();
DoWait(4);

SendText("^(a)");
SendText(text);
webBrowser1.Update();

elementTextArea = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(id);

elementTextArea.InnerText += "\nINNER TEXT";
Print("\nAdded Inner Text ABCD\n");

//elementTextArea.SetAttribute("placeholder", text + "PLACEHOLDER");
//Print("\nAdded place holder text abcd \n");

/*            
HtmlElementCollection elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement elem in elems)
{
    if (elem.GetAttribute("className").Equals("mentionsHidden"))
    {
        Print("\nAdded Second Text\n");
        elem.SetAttribute("value", text+"");
        break;
    }
}
*/

DoWait(3);

HtmlElementCollection elements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
{
    if (element.GetAttribute("className") == "_42ft _4jy0 _11b _4jy3 _4jy1 selected _51sy")
    {
        Print("\nPost Button Found\n");
        element.Focus();

        Print("\nFocus1\n");

        DoWait(2);

        SendText("~");

        element.InvokeMember("click");

        Print("\nClicked1\n");
```

Kindly help me, it took so much time.

Comment: Have you tried simulating keyboardinput? I am guessing, but it could be FB is checking your input (for url's etc.) and the check fails if you just add it "normally"

Answer (score 1):

When a post is submitted, it includes amongst other variables, these:

```
clp:{"cl_impid":"eeeeeeee","clearcounter":0,"elementid":"v_1_2n","version":"x","parent_fbid":1000000000000}
xhpc_message_text:
xhpc_message:
```

If you watch the source code of the page, the `_text` field above is a hidden field under the textarea which appears to reflect the same value.  And, when the textarea is initially clicked, `clp` as a hidden field is also adjusted.

You will have to exactly replicate every field submitted, clone the session, and then hope they don't change stuff by renaming a field or, worse, adding another one whose name is based off of a unique id and randomly placed in the code.

So, in short, there you go, but you may want to consider using their API even with the stupid "I'm your daddy," rules they now have in place for permissions... it may save you some serious headaches!